# UIViewRepresentable not sizing correctly in ScrollView

Tags: swiftui

I followed [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit) on using UIPageViewController with SwiftUI. Their guide works fine. However I ran into an issue, where if I have my `PageView` inside a `ScrollView` - the height of the `PageView` is no longer respected and I have to set the `frame` manually. Not ideal, as the content inside `PageView` is dynamic and thus, heights will vary.

This seems to be an issue with `ScrollView`; as I have another view - `UIViewRepresentable` - that is a simple wrapper around `WKWebView` - with the same issue.

Is there a way to have these views size themselves, inside a SwiftUI `ScrollView`?

If I place these views outside of a `ScrollView` and into a simple `VStack` for example, they size themselves correctly.

Comment: This is not an issue of ScrollView, it needs content size to know how much to scroll, so content must provide size to ScrollView, not vise-versa.

Comment: Thanks @Asperi - How do I provide this in a dynamic way? As mentioned, if I place these views outside of `ScrollView` - they are visible with their correct size.